# display the query rank number beside each post (WordPress Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using Elementor with Ele Custom Skin to display a list of posts.

I am also using a custom query to rank these posts by likes using another plugin.
the post with the most likes is first on the list; the post with the least at the bottom, etc.

I am trying to add a number on each post that displays the "rank" of that post in the query. the first post would be 1 the second 2 and so on.

The result would be something like the rank number on ranker.com

I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!